# How to upload large file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, video, file-upload

I want to upload a large file (video) up to size 40mb to sever.

When I upload a file size 2mb, it works very fine, but when the file size exceeds 4mb it times out.

This is how I'm uploading:

```
    $getTrailer = Input::file('Filedata');
    $trailer = time().'.'.$getTrailer->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = public_path().sprintf('/assets/admin/images/movie/trailers/videos/');
    Input::file('Filedata')->move($destinationPath, $trailer);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: I have shared server. can't access the php.ini file. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a third party code library called [BlueImp (link)](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)  which uses asynchronous javascript. It solves many problems with handling large file uploads via a web interface and offers a host of features that simplify it for the developer and the user such as:

- file chunking so upload limits can be circumvented
- drag and drop support
- multiple file support
- graceful fallback for browsers that need it

It might take a bit of effort to learn how to use it, but you might find it to be a very useful development tool that is relatively easy to customize.

Answer (score -2):

Use laravel disk storage .

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600197/how-to-upload-large-file-5mb-in-laravel-5)

Comment: This will not do anything because the file is too big