# How to upload large file > 5MB in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

May I know how to upload large file, more than 5Mb in Laravel 5? I am trying to upload around 10MB image file but it is not uploading, I searched a lot and updated following settings in `php.ini`

```
post_max_size = 500M;
memory_limit = 500M;
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

I have restarted Apache server but still having issue. Is there any other setting in `php.ini` or in Laravel to upload large files? Please help.

**Edit**

```
$image = $request->file('image');

            if($image && $image != '') {

                $extension  = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $imageName = $this->getUniqueName($extension);
                $image->move('gimages/profile_images/', $imageName);
                $profile_image = $imageName;
                $update_user_data['image'] = $profile_image;
            }
```

Thanks much!

Comment: You need to be more specific than **"it is not uploading"**. Please post the form that is initiating the upload, as well as the code that is responsible for processing the upload and explain what exactly is not working with it.

Comment: Do you receive any error?

Comment: No, when I print request in "Advanced Rest Client" to see POST data, it didn't show any data even other input fields @Jerodev

Comment: @SachinVairagi Do you see any post data? Try passing a text field as well, if you can't see this when you print the request object, then it is probably a rewrite issue as apposed to the upload.

Comment: @JohnDoe It doesn't show any post data when I submit large file, but when submit small file around 1MB, it prints post data and upload file successfully as well.

Comment: @SachinVairagi from experience this would suggest your app is crashing before a response is returned. What OS are you using?

Comment: @JohnDoe, I am using ubuntu 14.04 but testing web service in Advanced Rest Client

Comment: Do not ever use `getClientOriginalExtension` unless you know what you're doing. This could be changed easily by the client. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403558/get-an-image-extension-from-an-uploaded-file-in-laravel/48979159?noredirect=1#comment96306942_45887547

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to upload big files you should use streams. Here’s the code to do it:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$disk->put($targetFile, fopen($sourceFile, 'r+'));
```

PHP will only require a few MB of RAM even if you upload a file of several GB.

Source: https://murze.be/2015/07/upload-large-files-to-s3-using-laravel-5/

See Lrvl5 doc for usage and config of Storage :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem

Comment: I don't want to upload file on Amazon s3, I just want to upload it on our own server.

Comment: s3 is the config name in filesystem. You can call it anyway you like. See Storage doc on how to configure a private FTP server and use it seamlessly with Storage.

Answer (score 11):

I might be late here.

But as i thought someone might need a way to specifically stream file to

**local storage instead of s3**.

Here is how to stream a file to local storage. As [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#configuration) says

> **The Local Driver**
>
> When using the local driver, note that all file operations are
>   relative to the root directory defined in your configuration file. By
>   default, this value is set to the storage/app directory. Therefore,
>   the following method would store a file in storage/app/file.txt:
>
> ```
> Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
> ```

so to stream to local instead of using **s3** as @koalaok mentioned in the answer you could use **local**. so it will be something like

```
$disk = Storage::disk('local');
$disk->put($targetFile, fopen($sourceFile, 'r+'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @aimme , definitely it will help others.

Comment: What about Google drive? I am getting error while trying to upload in Google drive.But works fine for local storage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124539/laravel-file-storage-error

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel new version (+5.3) There is a 'Automatic Streaming' ability. U can use like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

// Automatically generate a unique ID for file name...
Storage::putFile('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'));

// Manually specify a file name...
Storage::putFileAs('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'), 'photo.jpg');
```

For more information please follow this docs and search for 'Automatic Streaming': https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem

Comment: Do we have to use `new File()` if the file is coming from `$request->file`?

Comment: @Michał yes, if u set this way, it will be saved on the localtion that u want

Comment: Sure but if we have a `$request` can we just do `Storage::putFile('photos', $request->file);` instead of using `new File('/path/to/photo')` and also get 'Automatic Streaming'?

Comment: Edit: Just tried both and can't tell the difference, both are still slow :/