# Get an image extension from an uploaded file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

I have been trying to get the extension from an uploaded file, searching on google, I got no results.

The file already exists in a path:

```
\Storage::get('/uploads/categories/featured_image.jpg);
```

Now, How can I get the extension of this file above?

Using input fields I can get the extension like this:

```
Input::file('thumb')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Thanks.

Comment: `getClientOriginalExtension()` gets wrong extension (user could send jpeg with png extension), so everytime you'd rather use `->extension()` method - it does not matter what class both `UploadedFile` and `File` have same method.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function built into PHP for that:

```
$info = pathinfo(storage_path().'/uploads/categories/featured_image.jpg');
$ext = $info['extension'];
```

Or more concisely, you can pass an option get get it directly;

```
$ext = pathinfo(storage_path().'/uploads/categories/featured_image.jpg', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: If I know that the file is .jpg, why would I try to find out the extension.

Comment: The answer assumes a dynamic path string, not a literal hard coded one. The hard coded path you see in the answer is just to demonstrate that overall point of using pathinfo().

Answer (score 111):

Tested in laravel 5.5

```
$extension = $request->file('file')->extension();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the best awnser. Works on Laravel 5.3+

Comment: It is slightly annoying that it bases itself on the mime type and thus returns `jpeg` if the extension is `jpg`

Comment: @Surya What's wrong with that?

Comment: @HashimAziz It means that if you are trying to find a file that is named `filename.jpg` you won't be finding it as it will look for `filename.jpeg`

Comment: @Surya I haven't checked the source code for it but I'd be very surprised if it works like that. It probably returns `jpeg` because that's the full extension/acronym (`jpg` is a convention from when DOS/Windows only supported 3-character extensions), but I would expect it to return that `jpeg` value for all extensions of JPEG listed in the JPEG MIME type. There are a lot more extensions than just those two - for the `image/jpeg` MIME type [Mozilla lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types) `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.jfif`, `.pjpeg`, and `.pjp`.

Comment: The MIME type approach is better from a programming perspective because the return value is consistent (so you don't have to use 5 conditionals to check for each extension), and from a security perspective because the extension can easily be faked (allowing an attacker to get an .exe onto your site that looks like a .jpeg).

Answer (score 85):

*The Laravel way*

Try this:

```
$foo = \File::extension($filename);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alfredo EM. I tried but just get "". The solution above works fine.

Comment: $extension = \File::extension('/uploads/categories/featured_image.jpg') really dont work =( ?

Comment: Copy and paste \File::extension('/uploads/categories/featured_image.jpg') ; and will return jpg

Comment: \File::guessExtension($filename) will work if you have a path from Storage without extension at the end ;)

Answer (score 71):

Yet another way to do it:

```
//Where $file is an instance of Illuminate\Http\UploadFile
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Comment: this is for laravel v 5

Comment: Danger: this gets CLIENT extension, not the real mime-type extension, to get that use  `extension()` instead

Comment: I have filename.jpg. When using `->extension()` it returns `jpeg` while `->getClientOriginalExtension()` returns `jpg` which is what I want.

Answer (score 17):

If you just want the extension, you can use `pathinfo`:

```
$ext = pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 //working code from laravel 5.2

 public function store(Request $request)
 {
          $file = $request->file('file');
            if($file)
            {
                    $extension =  $file->clientExtension();
            }
            echo $extension;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
return $picName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();
```

The `time()` function will make the image unique then the `.$request->file->extension()` gets the image extension for you.

You can use this it works well with Laravel 6 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
if($request->hasFile('video')){

    $video=$request->file('video');
    $filename=str_random(20).".".$video->extension(); 
    $path = Storage::putFileAs(
            '/', $video, $filename
     );
    $data['video']=$filename;
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Or can use the *Extension Splitter* `Trickster::getExtention()` function of https://github.com/secrethash/trickster

`Trickster::getExtention('some-funny.image.jpg');`
It returns `jpg`