# Laravel - How to get file extention from a path?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `File` class for getting extention of image url.

```
File::extension($image_path)
```

But my image URL is `example.com/images/new.png?v=21212154`

It returns `png?v=21212154`

How to get the value `png` only?

Comment: It gives you right extension, but you have values after `?`, remove it and then you get `.png` extension! Use `preg_replace` OR `explode()` for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403558/get-an-image-extension-from-an-uploaded-file-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this way:

```
$url = 'example.com/images/new.png?v=21212154';
$data = explode('?',$test);
$data = explode('/',$data[0]);
$filename = $data[2];

$extention = File::extension($filename);
```

**OR Try with below code.**

```
$result = File::extension($image_path)
$url =  strstr($result,"?");
echo str_replace($url,"",$result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`strstr`](http://php.net/strstr) will help you get values before some symbol:

```
$extension = 'png?v=21212154';
$real_extension = strstr($extension, '?', true);
// but if there's no '?' in `$extension`,
// `$real_extension` will be false
if ($real_extension) {
    $extension = $real_extension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pathinfo():

```
$extension = pathinfo($image_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

or

```
$info = pathinfo(image_path);
$extension = $info['extension'];
```