# Uploading large files in laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I've used `Laraval` to build my website. When I want to upload a `200mb` file, I see the following error.

```
illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException
```

How can i handle it ? I read a tutorial on this. I need to make changes to the `php.ini` file but I don't have this file in my host.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload large file > 5MB in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600197/how-to-upload-large-file-5mb-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various places where you could set the max post size.

If you use .htaccess, you could use the answer in [Increasing the maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size) and change the MB setting to your required one.

Generally the php.ini file can be in various places (or named a bit differently) depending your server's setup for which purpose you should ask you server administrator to do the change for you

Also if you have a validator on the request with a limit, you would need to set/increase it following [Laravel docs, validation max file size](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-max)